# iptables: when to use input or output with LAN connections?

Tags: ssh, iptables, local-area-network

In a SSH server/firewall (192.168.2.3) that has a LAN behind it, say 192.168.2.1/30, will the connection attempts made by the internal machines of the 192.168.2.1/30 network be interpreted by the firewall as incoming or outgoing connections?

If they are read as either incoming or outgoing, must I specify the destination or source address block (192.168.2.1/30)? Or when exactly are the -d or -s options needed?

My understanding is this: if I want those internal machines to make any new connections to the outside world, the rule goes like this.

`iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.2.8/30 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

and if the SSH server wanted to make new ssh connections to the outside world the rule would be this

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

In this case, should I leave out the ssh server ip address or include it in the rule?

Many thanks.

Comment: OUTPUT is internal to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INPUT` and `OUTPUT` are defined solely with respect to the system on which `iptables` is running.  To put it another way, `iptables` doesn't care what sort of systems are on any of its interfaces; it doesn't care whether an interface connects to your trusted LAN, or a DMZ, or a tank full of sharks with laptops.

`INPUT` always refers to traffic **entering** an interface from outside, with a view to terminating locally.  `OUTPUT` refers to traffic that originated locally and is about to **leave** via an interface.  `FORWARD` refers to traffic that's passing in one interface and straight out another.

The first you quote above mediates traffic from the `192.168.2.0/30` LAN on one interface, to the outside world on another, so that should both be in the `FORWARD` chain.  The second mediates traffic from the firewall to the world, so it's OK as it stands.

Though may I add in passing that that's not much of a LAN, and you should probably check that netmask because the firewall has an invalid address in the context of the LAN (it's the broadcast address, which shouldn't be assigned to a single host).  See [our famous canonical question on ipv4 subnetting](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for further discussion.

Comment: When you say `OUTPUT` refers to traffic that originated locally and is about to **leave** via an interface, do you mean traffic that is generated at the firewall or simply traffic that is originating from behind the firewall? A LAN for example. What sort of traffic then warrants an `OUTPUT` rule?

Comment: `OUTPUT` traffic originates locally, meaning on the firewall itself (eg, a DNS request going out, or a connection request to a foreign server).  The firewall *does not know or care* that one of your interfaces has what you consider to be an internal network on it; everything is outside, until configured otherwise.